# Ionic 3 sort file name by modified date (listDir)

Tags: ionic-framework

I have loaded all files from a directory and printed them in a list. But how can I print them by modified date order?

Comment: Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the tour of the site.

Answer (score 0):

A easy approach is to sort a array with data an then put the sorted array in a ionic list.
Here is a example:

```
component-code:
const activities = [
  { title: 'Hiking', date: new Date('2019-06-28') },
  { title: 'Shopping', date: new Date('2019-06-10') },
  { title: 'Trekking', date: new Date('2019-06-22') }
]
const sortedActivities = activities.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)

View:

    <div *ngFor="let activity of sortedActivities">
      {{activity.title}} / {{activity.date}} 
    </div>
```